# How could spin-orbit coupling works?

Tags: spin-orbit

I am not able to understand how does spin and orbital angular momentum interacts with each other, the spin magnetic field interacts with its own angular momentum magnetic field but how that can happen? How can one produces its own magnetic field and interacts with itself? I am not able to understand , is it due to radiation reaction that we used to study in electrodynamics?

Comment: It is within the theory of quantum mechanics . http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hydfin.html

Answer (score 0):

According to special relativity, when changing from an frame to a moving frame with respect to the original one, electric fields in the original frame can can behave (partially) as magnetic fields in the moving frame. Similarly magnetic fields in the original frame behave as electric fields in the moving frame (partially) .

In the usual atomic derivation of the spin-orbit coupling, you consider a hydrogen atom consisting of a charged proton, and a single electron orbiting the proton.

The electron is bound to the nucleus because the nucleus has a Coulomb electric field $\mathbf E(\mathbf r)=-e \hat{\mathbf r}/|\mathbf r|^2$. However the electron has also a magnetic moment related to its spin, and as the electron moves around the proton, it sees that the Coulomb field has also a magnetic component, thus there is a coupling between its magnetic moment at this apparent magnetic field due to its motion.

We call it spin-orbit because if the electron is not moving (orbiting), the electrons sees no interaction between its magnetic moment and $\mathbf E (\mathbf r)$.

### Not to be confused with hyperfine structure

Note that the electron produces a magnetic field by turning around the proton, and this leads to a coupling between the proton magnetic moment and the magnetic field created by the motion of the electron. However, this is NOT spin-orbit coupling, this is called hyper-fine splitting and it is a higher order correction to the spectrum of hydrogen.

### Where students get it wrong

In order to simplify the calculation, books go to the frame of the electron (which is non-inertial). In this frame it is like if the proton created a magnetic field by going around the electron, thus the spin couples to the magnetic field in the electron's frame. This leads to a lot of confusion but it is the simplest way to derive it.

Notwithstanding, you have to go back to the frame of the proton. In the derivation you need to use the formulas of special relativity to relate the apparent magnetic field into $\mathbf E(\mathbf r)$ in the frame of the proton (and add a factor of 2 because you did this in a non-inertial frame).

The final expression of the energy is:

$$H^{\rm (so)} = -\frac{1}{ m_\text{e}  c^2} |\mathbf E(\mathbf r)| \mathbf{L} \cdot \boldsymbol{\mu}_{\text e},$$

where $m_{\text e}c^2$ is rest energy of the electron due to the famous Einstein relativity relation, $\mathbf L$ is the angular momentum and $\boldsymbol{\mu}_{\text e}$ is the magnetic moment of the electron. You can see clearly that you need four ingredients for spin-orbit coupling to work an electric field $\mathbf E(\mathbf r)$, a moving particle, a magnetic moment and relativity.

Summary: spin-orbit coupling is the interaction of the electron magnetic moment with the electric potential of the nucleus (due to relativistic effects). It is not related to its own self-interaction.